# How to prove correctness of code that finds the maximum number in an array recursively?

Tags: python, algorithm

I've written a recursive function to find the greatest value in a given array. I'm wondering how to prove (or disprove) that it works correctly and to find a more appropriate implementation.

It returns the correct answer for the arrays I tested with, but can I be sure it always will? And is using the `pop` function an appropriate approach?

I searched the internet for code that solves this with recursion and could not find any code that is similar to my simple method code.

```
def max(items):
   if len(items) == 1:
      return items[0]
   if items[0] >= items[1]:
      items.pop(1)
      return max(items)
   items.pop(0)
   return max(items)

print(max([9,1,2,11,4,5,7,8, 10]))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "correct"?  Returns the correct answer?  Well, you have the code right in front of you, so TEST IT and see!  Why are you asking us??

Comment: There will come a day when people will ask ChatGPT whether the expression `1+1` really evaluates to 2.

Comment: @JohnGordon It returns the correct answer, but I though the code is not well-structured for finding the maximum number using a recursive function because it uses the pop function. I searched the internet for code implementing this algorithm and could not find any similar code that looks like to my simple method code.

Comment: Using the `pop` function does not make it not recursive.

Comment: But as a side note, it is not very nice that your code mutates the list, and so the caller is left with a list that has all of its contents (except one value) removed. But that is not your question.

Comment: If I used this function, I would be surprised to find that my item list had been reduced to only one item.  But I suppose it could be useful in some rare circumstance.

Comment: Even if it works for small lists, you’re going to run into the stack limit for lists with more than ~1000 elements. When dealing with lists you should seek to break the list into halves until you get to individual elements, not whittle it down one-by-one. Repeated halving will make stack usage grow as O(log(len(list))) rather than O(len(list)).

Comment: Got it, thank you. So, for resolving this question to find the maximum number recursively in an array, it's not usual to remove items from it. However, it works. If the elements of the array will remain after the process, it will be better.

Comment: There's no real reason to even use recursion for this purpose.  An iterative solution works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is correct.

We can use a [proof by induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction):

#### The base case:

If the array has just one value, that value is returned, which is correct.

#### The induction step:

Here we assume that the function works correctly for array sizes of 1...−1, and see what happens with an array of size  (where  is greater than 1):

In that case the least of the first two values is removed (via either `pop(0)` or `pop(1)`: this action ensures that the greatest value stays in the list. If the value that is popped happens to be the greatest value, then this must mean that the other of the first two values was equal to it, and so the array still has that greatest value.

The array now has size −1, and we know that for that size the function returns the correct result (the greatest value).

This completes the proof.

### Remarks

By choosing =1 as base case, we don't consider =0. In that case the function will raise an error, but as the notion of greatest is undefined for an empty collection, this should not be a problem.

It is not nice that this function mutates the given list. The caller will be surprised to notice that all but one element was removed from their list.

Stack space is limited, which puts a limit on the size of list this function can handle. Obviously, an iterative function would not have this problem, but I suppose this is an exercise (Python already has a `max` function).

### Alternative

An alternative, non-destructive, recursive version could be achieved by using an *index* that is passed along as second argument (defaulting to 0). This index represents the start of the subarray that is being considered.

It seems also more elegant to *first* perform the recursive call and *then* compare the maximum you get from it with the *current* value (the first value of the subarray):

```
def max(items, i=0):
    value = items[i]
    if i == len(items) - 1:
        return value
    maxrest = max(items, i + 1)
    return value if value > maxrest else maxrest
```

To solve the stack limit issue, you can supply the function with a window (two indices), and divide it into halves for two recursive calls:

```
def max(items, start=0, stop=-1):
    if stop == -1:
        stop = len(items)  # Initialise when not provided
    if stop - start == 1:
        return items[start]
    mid = (start + stop) // 2
    maxleft = max(items, start, mid)
    maxright = max(items, mid, stop)
    return maxleft if maxleft > maxright else maxright
```

Now the stack space used is O(log), which will not be a problem for lists in practice.